# return text back to default div after hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

this code is not working when it come to returning the text div back to default. I have 12 links and everything works except for returning the text back to default content before hover

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
        $("#MenuBar1 li")
            .mouseover(function () {
            $("#back")
                .attr("src", $(this)
                .data("img"));
            $('.description')
                .text($(this)
                .data('description'));
        })
            .mouseout(function () {
            $("#back")
                .attr("src", $("#back")
                .data("original"));
            $('.description')
                .text($('.description')
                .data('change'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 357px; position: relative; top: -357px; left: 5px;"
id="content">
    <img src="http://6/images/pic1.jpg" alt="logo's" width="357"
    height="241" id="back" data-original="http://64.197.156.235/images/pic1.jpg"
    />
</div>
<div id="change" class="description" 
      style="background-color: #CCC; 
      width: 338px; 
      position: relative; 
      top: -359px; 
      left: 5px; 
      padding: 15px 10px 15px; 
      color: #414141; 
      font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 266px;">
      change text for each link with each picture then set back to default
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable by humans.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
        $('.description').text($(this).data('description'));
    }).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
  $('.description').text($('.description').data('change'));
    });
});

Comment: <div style="width: 357px; position: relative; top: -357px; left: 5px;" id="content"> <img
             src="http://64images/pic1.jpg" 
             alt="logo's" width="357" height="241" id="back"
             data-original="http://64/images/pic1.jpg" /> </div>
    <div id="change" class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 338px; position: relative; top: -359px; left: 5px; padding: 15px 10px 15px; color: #414141; font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 266px;" >change text for each link with each picture then set back to default</div>

Comment: @dyscool I edited the formatting in your question

Comment: thank you, a ton, can anyone assist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be defining the default text anywhere in particular. Try adding this to the start of your code (just after the `.ready(function() {`):

```
var defaultText = $(".description").text();
```

Then, when setting the `.description`'s text back, use:

```
$(".description").text(defaultText);
```

Comment: I am new to JQuery so would it be like follows:

Comment: I am new to JQuery so would it be like follows: $("#MenuBar1 li")
.mouseover(function () { var defaultText = $(".description").text(); $('.description') .text($(this).data('description'));}) .mouseout(function () { $(".description").text(defaultText); });

Comment: how do i call it out on my div tag withe the text?

Comment: no changes one inputed. <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MenuBar1 li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#back").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
  var defaultText= $(".description").text();
        $(".description").text($(this).data("description"));
    }).mouseout(function() { 
        $("#back").attr("src", $("#back").data("original"));
  $(".description").text(defaultText);
    });
});  
</script>

Comment: <div class="description" style="background-color: #CCC; width: 338px; position: relative; top: -359px; left: 5px; padding: 5px 10px 15px; color: #414141; font: arial, Trebuchet MS; height: 256px;" id="Text" >